# Считывание даты рождения из формы в Java приложении

Tags: java, java-ee, дата, jsp, servlet

Есть веб-приложение на сервлетах и `jsp.` Нужно считать дату рождения в формате `YYYY/MM/DD`. Не могу понять, как преобразовать дату в `String`, ведь `getParameter()` принимает только строковое выражение.

```
public class User  {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateOfBirth;

    ...//конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры
}

public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("views/add.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String password = req.getParameter("pass");
        SimpleDateFormat dateOfBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
        String date = dateOfBirth.format(new Date());
        User user = new User(name, password, date);
        Model model = Model.getInstance();
        model.add(user);

        req.setAttribute("userName", name);
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как дата в запросе выглядит? Вот так можно сделать:           `String date = req.getParameter("date");` ? Что в строке будет? Я правильно понимаю, вам нужно это значение под формат подогнать ?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе не совсем понятно где происходит получение даты.

Пример ниже должен помочь разобраться как преобразовать строку в дату:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String date = "2020/05/02";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
    Date parse = format.parse(date);
    System.out.println(parse);
}
```